# Updating MySQL Table A based on value from Table B joined via intersection Table C

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many, intersection

I’ve been muddling through using MySQL for some time, but it’s still not really ‘in’ my brain yet, so I’m hoping I can make myself understood here, and that someone else can help me clear this particular cerebral mire of mine. :-)

I have two MySQL tables, `writers` and `abstracts`, and an intersection table `writer_abstract` that joins them in a many-to-many relationship.

In the `abstracts` table, there’s a field `accepted` (a boolean) to indicate whether or not a certain abstract has been accepted for publication. Similarly, in the `writers` table, there is a field `published` (also a boolean) that indicates whether or not an author has had anything published (or accepted for publication).

The intersection table is very simple: it has an auto-incrementing `id` field, a `writer_id` field, and an `abstract_id` field. I can select back and forth between `writers` and `abstracts` using the intersection table without problems.

When an abstract is accepted or rejected, `abstracts.accepted` is set to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

What I would like to do is, in a single MySQL statement, update `writers.published` in all rows and set it to `TRUE` if there are any abstracts by that author whose `accepted` field is `TRUE`. But I can’t figure out how to phrase the `UPDATE` statement to get it to work.

My best efforts are something like this:

```
UPDATE writers LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT abstracts.id AS aid, abstracts.accepted AS aacc FROM writer_abstract
      LEFT JOIN abstracts ON writer_abstract.abstract_id = writers.id
      WHERE aacc = TRUE AND writers.id = writer_abstract.author )
AS res
SET published = TRUE
```

Obviously, this doesn’t work (I have an error in my syntax near `SET published = TRUE`). But this can’t be something that isn’t fairly easily done, surely?!

Any help much appreciated! :-)

**Update**

Based on KingFisher’s reply, here is the version that actually did what I wanted (note the `RIGHT JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`—the former naturally affected all rows in `writers`, which wasn’t what I wanted):

```
UPDATE writers RIGHT JOIN
    ( SELECT author, accepted FROM writer_abstract
      LEFT JOIN abstracts ON writer_abstract.abstract_id = writers.id
      WHERE accepted = TRUE )
AS res ON res.author = writers.id
SET published = TRUE
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `id` column in the `writer_abstract` table.  Just use the writer ID and abstract ID, together, as the primary key.

Comment: Yeah, that column’s mostly just there ’cause I like to have an auto-incrementing `id` column in all my tables. Go OCD. :-)

Comment: That's called a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), and it makes sense in many cases.  But for a table like `writer_abstract` that just links two other tables, it's entirely redundant, because the two other columns (which correspond to the surrogate keys in other tables) already uniquely identify the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `on` clause with join of `writers` table and your `subquery`.

Comment: Oh, d’oh! But of course—even I ought to have seen that immediately. Thank you so much for proving that I’m not going crazy, just up too late!